# Как убрать фигурные скобки на выходе?

Tags: javascript

При response получаю объект `{ "usd": 0 }`. Как мне из него получить строку `0 usd`?

Comment: Какая строка в итоге должна получиться? И зачем вообще убирать скобки?

Comment: отобразить данные на клиенте .  должно выйти так 0 usd

Comment: Парсите JSON и там можно извлечь: `parsedData.usd`.

Comment: Вон как народ старается, скажите тип данных: строка (тогда JSON) или это форматированный вывод, а на деле там объект?

Comment: Можно просто обращаться к свойствам объекта при выводе

Comment: тип данных объект

Comment: @ЛенаФролова почему вы убрали галочку с моего ответа? Вопрос не решён?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так:

```js
var response = {"usd": 0};
for(var i in response)
{
 console.log(response[i] + ' ' + i);
}
```

Или вот так:

```js
var response = {"usd": 0};
var key = Object.keys(response)[0];
console.log(response[key] + ' ' + key);
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример функции для парсинга из строкового представления объекта (JSON), с любым количеством свойств:

```js
let response = '{ "usd": 0.98, "eur": 42, "rur": 1234 }',
    valStrings = parseResponse(response); 
console.log(valStrings.join('\n')); 

function parseResponse(json) {
  let result = [], 
      obj = JSON.parse(json); 
  for (let key in obj) 
    result.push(obj[key] + ' ' + key.toUpperCase()); 
  return result; 
}
```

Функция возвращает массив строк формата `<значение> <валюта>`, по строке на каждое свойство.
Если JSON содержит другие свойства (которые не надо преобразовывать), добавьте условие в цикл.

Answer (score 0):

Условия непонятны, но может так?

```
alert('usd ' + response.usd);
```

Comment: я делаю запрос к бд и передаю данные переменной
this.balance = response.data.users.balance. и в результате у меня выводит  { "usd": 0 }.

Comment: @ЛенаФролова, тут стоит добавить то, как именно ты выводишь.

Comment: `this.balance = Object.keys(response.data.users.balance).reduce((a,c)=>(a.push(\`${c} ${response.data.users.balance[c]}\`), a), []).join("\n")`